# How is professor Mc.Gonagall present in Crimes of Grindelwald?

Tags: character, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Is there any official explanation or quote regarding the appearance of Professor McGonagall in 'Crimes of Grindelwald', given that McGonagall is born in 1935 (CoG takes place in 1927 or 1928)?

Was this Professor McGonagall's mother 'Isobel'? Was there any proof she worked in Hogwarts?

Comment: See - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198713/who-is-the-professor-mcgonagall-in-the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Comment: I remember that scene where Albus tells his student to go with Professor McGonagall, he mentions Professor McGonagall. So, it could be both.

Comment: ...and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/198871/in-what-ways-do-the-fantastic-beast-series-contradict-original-canon

Comment: oh ok thank you ! the first explanation is good,. the second link's accepted answer is somewhat off

Comment: It's a blunder. Because the screenplay mentions "Minerva McGonagall" specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I [answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/198725/58193) this over on SFF I'll just copy and paste my answer here as it is the same question.

---

**It is unclear as to who this McGonagall is, though it is almost certainly the Minerva we know from the main *Harry Potter* series.**

The *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay* by J. K. Rowling only states her to be a "young Minerva McGonagall" (emphasis mine):

> *The class laughs. The door opens. TRAVERS, THESEUS, and four other AURORS enter, **YOUNG MINERVA MCGONAGALL** behind them.*
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 64</sub>

Of course the timeline doesn't work out if this is the same Minerva from the main series as she was most likely born on the 4th of October, 1935 (as detailed in the [linked question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91430/58193)) whereas *The Crimes of Grindelwald* takes place in 1927/1928. We also have the scenes from 13 year old Newt and Leta at Hogwarts so from approximately a decade earlier. The film opens in 1927, 6 months after *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (set in 1926), and then a further 3 months pass before the main events of the film.

> **EXT. NEW YORK, AMERICAN MINISTRY OF MAGIC—1927—NIGHT**
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 1</sub>

> **SPIELMAN** *(Germanic)* ... you’ll be glad to be rid of him, I expect.
>
> **PICQUERY** We’d be more than happy to keep him here in custody.
>
> **SPIELMAN** Six months are enough. It’s time for him to answer for his crimes in Europe.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 3</sub>

> **EXT. OVERCAST LONDON, WHITEHALL—THREE MONTHS LATER—AFTERNOON**
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 17</sub>

---

It is possible that this could be Minerva's grandmother, who she was named after, who is described as "an immensely talented witch" so could have taught at Hogwarts. Though this points to Isobel's grandmother not Robert's and so most likely wasn't a McGonagall so it is unlikely to have been her.

> The birth of the young couple’s first child, Minerva, proved both a joy and a crisis. Missing her family, and the magical community she had given up for love, Isobel insisted on naming her newborn daughter after her own grandmother, an immensely talented witch.
>
> <sub>[Pottermore, Professor McGonagall By J.K. Rowling, Childhood](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall)</sub>

Comment: thank you for this answer here ! i dint know what i was supposed to do tbh !  also, so its NOT minerva mc gonagall the grandma of mc gonagall that we know,, what a timeline mix up ! :/