# Who is the one asking Flamel to fight?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, a person is asking Flamel to go and fight.

We only hear the voice. Who is it?

Answer (score 1):

## Eulalie Hicks

FWIW you do see her portrait in the book as Flamel flicks through it.

> *FLAMEL flicks open another page. EULALIE HICKS, a young American professor at Ilvermorny, looks around, worried.*
>
> **EULALIE** What’s happening?
>
> **FLAMEL** Exactly what he said would happen. Grindelwald rallies tonight at the cemetery, and there will be death!
>
> **EULALIE** Then you gotta go!
>
> **FLAMEL** *(panicked)* What? I haven’t seen action in two hundred years...
>
> **EULALIE** You can do this, Flamel. We believe in you.
>
> <sub>*Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald - The Original Screenplay*, Scene 86</sub>

Comment: Since you have the book, you can answer the McGonagall question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93979/how-is-professor-mc-gonagall-present-in-crimes-of-grindelwald

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Ironically, perhaps, I'm the one who answered that over on SFF.

Comment: Well I was too shocked by the "Crystal ball of plot" not being revealed to an usefull char to read the name. I was like "ho I missed it",  who is she?